# Error while entering in terminal

Tags: wine

I am having an issue with running a program using `wine` on my Ubuntu.

Whenever I use a terminal command to run my exe file, I get this error below, and unable to run it:

```
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\PROGRAM.exe" not found
```

Also, I tried using the `Open with another application` option from the GUI, but wine does not appear on the list of available programs.

What seems to be the cause for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to run a program with the wrong directory / name or it does not exist at all on your machine, so wine tries to run it as if it was a program under Windows' `$PATH` environment variable (`C:\\windows\\system32\`).

Overall, to run an exe using wine with the terminal, your command should be wine and a directory where this exe file is located:

```
user@machine:~/Desktop$ wine my_prog.exe
```

Or:

```
user@machine:~$ wine Desktop/my_prog.exe
```

If the program does not exist at the given directory, wine will search for it under your emulated `system32` directory.

This is also a method of running Windows programs located in system32 - try it:

- `wine cmd`
- `wine notepad`
- `wine ipconfig`

Regarding `Open with another application` option from the GUI - I am not sure I ever stumbled upon this option with wine, and pretty sure it is not supported.

Comment: well you give me some use but this code
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\program.exe" not found
appear when i enter in terminal: wine program.

Comment: Every program? For example suppose you have a an exe file named `foo.exe` located at `~/Desktop`, does using `wine ~/Desktop/foo.exe` gives you this error? Does `wine notepad` also gives you this error?